# What is the purpose of inverse distance?

Tags: distance, matrix-inverse

In many econometric models, they use the inverse distance, instead of just distance. For example, if they are looking at the impact of distance to CBD on land values, they might use the inverse distance. What is the reasoning for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Distance gets larger the farther away something is. Inverse distance gets smaller as distance increases. This quantifies the notion that nearer things have more influence than things farther away.